# CodeContract problem with ensures

Tags: .net, code-contracts

I got the following code:

```
    protected virtual string FormatException(Exception exception, int intendation)
    {
        Contract.Requires(intendation >= 0);
        Contract.Requires<ArgumentNullException>(exception != null);
        Contract.Ensures(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()));

        var msg = exception.ToString().Replace("\r\n", "\r\n".PadRight(intendation, '\t'));
        string text = string.Format("\r\n******* EXCEPTION ********\r\n\t{0}", msg);
        return text;
    }
```

It gives me

> Warning   19  CodeContracts: ensures unproven: !String.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result())

Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if the `String.Format()` function has any contracts but it could only promise that the `result != null`, an empty string is a valid result.

I checked: String.Format() only  *ensures result != null*

You can simply fix it by inserting an `Assume()` :

```
Contract.Assume(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(text));
return text;
```

But I would seriously reconsider making *result is not empty* part of your contract here. Does it really matter to the callers?

Comment: Yes it do matter when handling the result. MSDN doesn't document when it returns null? Won't it always return a string with the format string has been specified?

Comment: The _contract_ for String.Format() only specifies != null. Going beyond that would require a complicated expression based on the parameters. Maybe not impossible but rarely desired. You seem to have an exceptional case.